# Proving Equivalence with Logical Laws

Tags: logic

I'm having a bit of trouble proving that:
$\neg p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is equivalent to $q \rightarrow (p \vee r)$.

I tried using the implication law twice to get to this: 
$$p \vee (\neg q \vee r).$$
This is where I get stuck.  Can anyone help out with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can swap things around to get $$\neg q \vee (p \vee r)$$ due to commutativity and associativity. By using the implication law once again (in reverse direction), we arrive at the required expression.

Comment: Can you show your steps from where i left off.  Where you ised commutatvity and assocativity law

Comment: @Elchavo18 Is this not obvious? $$p\vee(\neg q\vee r)\\(p\vee\neg q)\vee r\\(\neg q\vee p)\vee r\\\neg q\vee(p\vee r)$$